# Send Blob over POST http request with string values

Tags: post, xmlhttprequest, blob

Hi I am trying to do a http POST request to send some blob data. But I also need to send some string values with it for authentication (jwt).

```
let options = {uname: user.uname, authKey: user.authKey, video: qde.debrief.blob}
let xhr = await xhrRequest(`${serverIp}/api/file`, "POST", options, 'none');
prom.push(xhr);
```

And the xhrRequest method is

```
//xhr function with url input and isValid and data output
function xhrRequest(url, type, body, header) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                resolve({ error: false, body: JSON.parse(xhr.response) });
            } else if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status !== 200) {
                resolve({ error: true, body: JSON.parse(xhr.response) });
            }
        }
        xhr.timeout = 5000;
        xhr.ontimeout = () => {
            resolve({ error: true, body: "Error Connecting to server" });
        }
        xhr.onerror = function () {
            resolve({ error: true, body: "Error Connecting to server" });
        }
        xhr.open(type, url, true);
        if (type == "POST") {
            if(!header){
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            }
            xhr.send(body)
        } else {
            xhr.send();
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Use a FormData object.

Comment: Tried that, but my express middleware is not picking the request up. I assume with the FormData it would come under request.body?